# Pass in props in react component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, navbar

I don't know if this is possible but I basically want to pass arguments into a react component basically this

```
import React from 'react';
const Navbar = (index) => {return(<div>{index}</div>)}
export default Navbar;
```

So I can later do this

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from '../../components/Navbar/Navbar.jsx';
const Home () => {return(<Navbar index=0 />)}
export default Home;
```

I'm actually very new to the programming world if it wasn't noticeable so help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: this is possible and the right way one should be doing except `<Navbar index=0 />`, instead this should be `<Navbar index={0} />`. Please note the curly braces :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it is

```
const Navbar = (props) => {return(<div>{props.index}</div>)}

const Home = () => {return(<Navbar index={0} />)}
```

A functional react component accepts a single argument (often called `props`) which provide all the properties.

Read more here https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: an alternative if you want want to do `props.x` every couple of lines would be to do `const MyComponent = ({ some, prop, names }) => {( <p>{ some } { prop } { names }</p> )}`